# Custom multi friend selector Facebook Unity3d

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to make sure about can we make custom multi friend selector of facebook in unity ?

I got the [multi friend selector link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/v2.2?locale=en_GB) . but there is no reference code regarding unity.

So if anyone has tried that feature then help me and share here.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Will you can get friends list using one of my plugins ([Android Native](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10825) or [Mobile Social](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15066)), you will also find friend list implementation example inside, here is example scene screenshot:

http:// i.stack.imgur.com/68y5R.jpg

And in case you do not want to use paid solutions you can get free Unity FB SDK for here.

https:// developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads?locale=en_GB

And use

```
FB.API("/me?fields=friends.limit(10).fields(first_name,id,last_name,name,link,locale,location)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, FriendsDataCallBack);
```

To get your friends data. More info:

https:// developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends?locale=en_GB

P.S. Sorry for url formats. I ma new here, and can not add more than 2 links to my replay

Comment: The default Facebook multi-friend selector allows users to select from entire friend list. However, the friends api only returns the friends who are also connected to the game